# How to display all objects with rigid bodies in the outliner?

Tags: interface, rigid-body-simulation, outliner

In a complexer scene there can be easily hundreds of objects.

Is there some setting/filter so that i can see all objects with rigid bodies in the outliner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this solution is not as easy as desired, but here's what you can do: Make sure all objects are deselected with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Now, usually Blender creates collection called *RigidBodyWorld* which is not shown as collection in the *Outliner*, but it exists. So in *3D Viewport* press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> > *Select Grouped* > *Collection* and from the collections choose "RigidBodyWorld".

[image: select collections]

Now all rigid bodies are selected. To see only them in *Outliner*, go to the *Filter* menu and switch from "All" to "Selected". Not exactly what you want maybe because everything else is hidden, but I hope it helps.

[image: filter selected]

Comment: great, thank you!

Comment: @Chris What I sometimes do if I have lots of objects in a scene, I usually create a new collection for special objects to be able to find them, like a collection for rigid bodies, or effectors or fluid objects etc. The simple way is with such an object selected you can press M and move it to the new collection. However, if you want the object to also stay located in its original collection, you can press Shift+M. This links the selected object to a collection so it appears under both of them. That's what grouping was in older Blender versions.

Comment: yes, that's what i do too. But often here you got projects (from the questions) with no collections at all and all are in chaos. And i didn't want to click all single objects to check whether they have rigid bodies or not...because i am laaaaazy....! ;)

Comment: @Chris Ah okay, didn't know you were talking about chaotic files created by others ;)

Comment: I guess you know that when it's not rigid bodies, but certain objects like lights, camera, revolution (oops, I got carried away) or meshes, curves, empties etc. you can choose _Select All By Type_.

Comment: @Chris kann dir ja hier leider keine PN schreiben... langsam verstehe ich dein Problem mit MF und seiner Engstirnigkeit

Comment: in meinem Profil ist meine email gepflegt. Kannst du gerne schreiben. ;)